# Displaying message after successful registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I don't want to login users after registration but redirect them login page. So far i am successful overriding Register() in RegisterController.

```
public function Register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
        );
        }

        return redirect('/login')->with('message','Successfully Registered');
    }
```

But the success message is not appearing. And when i return directly to view:

```
return view('auth.login')->with('message','Successfully registered');
```

The messsage is displayed correctly in login page but the url goes to `/register` this means after i try to login, it goes to registration form instead? What is the actual solution to do this?

Comment: trying doing it with route

Comment: Routes shouldn't matter, they will finally land on the same controller, if that was the problem it is highly unlikely that the view method would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash to the session:

```
$request->session()->flash('message', 'content');
```

Then check if the session exists with:

```
session()->has('message')
```

and if it does display it with `session()->get('message')`

Answer (score 3):

From Laravel 5.4 you can override the [`registered()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.html#method_registered) method in your `RegisterController` to flash the message to the session.

```php
/**
 * The user has been registered.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $request->session()->flash('notification', 'Thank you for subscribing!');
}
```

Then you can display the message in the view with the `session()` helper.

```
@if (session()->has('notification'))
    <div class="notification">
        {!! session('notification') !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Write this code in the view where this message must display:

```
{{ Session::get('message'`) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly give this flash before the redirect in the Register function :

```
    session()->flash('success', 'You have Successfully Registered'); 
    return redirect('/login');
```

Then put the below statement to get the message in the view :

```
   {{Session::get('success')}}
```